# Inexperienced with computers - Did I accidentally upload my files on to the internet?

Tags: google-chrome, mac, security

I posted this question on reddit yesterday and I am grateful that someone replied to me. But I wanted to get a second opinion because I still feel a little anxious. I am not sure if this is the right place to post my question, but here it is anyways:

I am an individual who is very inexperienced with computers. Yesterday I accidentally dragged one of my folders, which contained a lot of personal information, onto my Google Chrome browser (I was on google.com), and it looked liked the directory of my folder was readily available on the browser. My question is: did I just upload my personal information onto the internet?

Thank you for any responses.

Comment: You cannot upload a folder by dragging and dropping a folder or file into a browser except if it's a website with an upload capability and 98.99% of websites don't support uploading folders.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, you did not. Chrome only displayed the folder locally, in the same manner Windows Explorer displays folders locally.

A way to know if a web browser such as Google Chrome or Internet Explorer is displaying a local file or folder is to check the url. If it starts with "file:///" it's local.

Comment: @charles You're welcome. Given how many sites support drag-and-drop interactions nowadays you had a legitimate concern. Kudos to you for being a careful user, and I don't think you'll remain inexperienced for long, having figured out reddit and stack exchange already!